# QSort returns wrong (scrambled?) numbers in cmp function

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I want to use QSort in my program to sort elements in the pointer to pointers to struct. The first element is ok but then it is messed up. The function seems to read some elements but in wrong order / position.

Here is my code

```
...

typedef struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} Date;

...

// Sorts the date date_num - the number of entered dates, dates - pointer to pointers to structs of dates
void sort_dates(int* date_num, Date** dates){

    // Normalize the year
    int d; // The date
    for(d=0;d<*date_num;d++){
        if(dates[d]->year >= 90 && dates[d]->year <= 99){
            dates[d]->year = (dates[d]->year)+1900;
        } else{
            dates[d]->year = (dates[d]->year)+2000;
        }
    }

    qsort(dates[0], *date_num, sizeof(Date), compare);

}

int compare(const void* a, const void* b){

    Date* date1 = (Date*)a;
    Date* date2 = (Date*)b;

    // Concatenate year, month and day
    long num1 = date1->year;
    long num2 = date2->year;

    // Concatenate month
    num1 = num1*100+(date1->month);
    num2 = num2*100+(date2->month);

    // Concatenate day
    num1 = num1*100+(date1->day);
    num2 = num2*100+(date2->day);

    printf("num1 = %d %d %d, num2 = %d %d %d\n", date1->year, date1->month, date1->day, date2->year, date2->month, date2->day);

    //return (num2 - num1);
    return 0; // Sorting Temporarily disabled

}
```

After input:

```
January 1 01
January 1 00
February 28 99
July 17 12
September 10 12
July 1 00
June 30 90
August 25 06
May 27 08
October 1 03
```

The program converts month names to numbers and stores dates in `Date** dates` . After executing this I expect something like this in format
`num1 = year month day, num2=year month day` :

```
num1 = 2001 1 1, num2 = 2012 9 10
num1 = 2012 9 10, num2 = 2000 7 1
...
```

But it actually returns something like that:

```
num1 = 2001 1 1, num2 = 0 0 0
num1 = 0 2000 1, num2 = 33 0 0
num1 = 1 0 33, num2 = 0 2000 1
num1 = 2001 1 1, num2 = 1 0 33
num1 = 0 0 0, num2 = 1 0 33
num1 = 2 28 0, num2 = 0 0 1999
num1 = 2012 7 17, num2 = 0 0 0
num1 = 0 33 0, num2 = 2012 7 17
num1 = 2 28 0, num2 = 0 33 0
num1 = 0 0 1999, num2 = 0 33 0
num1 = 2001 1 1, num2 = 2 28 0
num1 = 0 0 0, num2 = 2 28 0
num1 = 1 0 33, num2 = 2 28 0
num1 = 0 2000 1, num2 = 2 28 0
num1 = 33 0 0, num2 = 2 28 0
```

I suspect that there could be a problem with the size of each block to be sorted as ex. year is in some elements at wrong position (different than first) but logically it seems to be right.

Comment: shouldnt it be `sizeof(*Date)`

Comment: @PeterMiehle That's a syntax error. :) Perhaps you meant `sizeof (Date *)`.

Comment: upps sorry, too much golang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
qsort(dates[0], *date_num, sizeof(Date), compare);
```

is wrong, if you want to sort `dates` then pass `dates` to `qsort()`, not its first element. Also the size you want to sort is the size of a pointer, i.e. `sizeof (Date *)`, or ever better `sizeof *dates`.

Further, your comparison function fails to take into account that it will be passed pointers to elements of `dates`, i.e. pointers to pointers to `Date`. This means it should start:

```
static int compare(const void* a, const void* b){
    const Date * const date1 = *(const Date**) a;
    const Date * const date2 = *(const Date**) b;
```

Again, this change is needed since the comparison function to `qsort()` is passed two pointers to elements in the array that is getting sorted. That's a reasonable thing to pass, it can't pass the elements themselves (it doesn't know their types), but a `const void *` can point at any kind of data. Since your array elements are of type `Date *` (pointer to `Date`), that means the actual values sent to `compare()` are pointers to pointers to `Date` (i.e. `Date **`).

Finally, there's no point in dropping `const` inside it, so don't do that.

Comment: To clarify the last paragraph: `Date* date1 = (Date*)a;` should be `Date* date1 = *(Date**)a;`

Comment: Yeah, it works, Thank you! Can you explain me how these how this change in `compare` function work? It is so confusing for me